# What's causing my gas oven ignitor to become dirty?

Tags: gas, oven, natural-gas

For months, my gas oven has been having issues igniting. The issue is somewhat intermittent but every time I run into this, I take a piece of sandpaper and rub it against the ignitor. This seems to clean off some kind of dirt or residue allowing the ignitor to spark and light the burner. The problem became more and more frequent to the point where it would stop igniting the 2nd or 3rd burn after cleaning the ignitor (5-10 minutes). I purchased an OEM ignitor and replaced it but I'm still having the same problem. The only way I'm able to get the oven to light is by first cleaning it with sandpaper.

What is causing this frequent problem. If this were over the span of weeks or months, I would sort of understand. But the fact that the ignitor stops working before the oven preheats doesn't make sense, and is starting to get really inconvenient.

[EDIT]
Something else that I forgot to include is that the broiler ignitor works fine. We rarely use it but every time I run into issues with the oven's ignitor, I test the broiler to make sure it's working. I feel that this takes away from argument that it could be dirty gas or a dirty environment, unlesl you can argue that the residue/dirt is settling on the bottom of the oven.

Could it be dirty natural gas or something else?

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A couple of possibilities come to mind.  Is it possible that your gas is "dirty"?  Is this natural gas or bottle gas?  You might contact your supplier and see if they have some issues in your area.  It may also be that there is dirt in the environment that is contaminating the igniter.  Is it dirty/dusty around where the oven is installed?  Pet hair can also cause problems.

Comment: These are all good points/questions. It's a natural gas oven so our gas comes to us through a public utility. I should also note that I had a similar issue with the ignitor on our furnace this past winter. I'm going to contact the gas company but I don't have much faith that I'll resolve the issue there. I don't feel that the inside of the oven is really dirty at all and I'm sure that underneath/behind the oven has a normal amount of dust and dirt. Cleaning this space out still isn't a bad idea. We do have two cats but I don't feel that much or any hair get's into the oven and is burned.

Comment: @jwh20 I added an edit about our broiler ignitor working without issue. Not sure if that changes your thinking at all.

Comment: Could it be condensation, if the air is humid and room-temperature fluctuates?